Shopify GraphQL - Create Product with mutation CreateProductWithOptions
I have a problem with new product model. I want to create a example product with graphql
my referance: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/unstable/mutations/productCreate?example=Create+a+product+with+product+options+and+option+values&language=cURL#argument-input

As you can see in this screenshot, this product have Color and Size options and there are 2 values for each option.
When I use this example,

It generates only first values. I tried lots of methods but I could not solve it.
My php code;
$accessToken = $shopify->get_token();
    $shopUrl = 'https://' . $shopify->get_shop() . '/admin/api/unstable/graphql.json';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $shopUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.$accessToken,
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\"query\": \"mutation CreateProductWithOptions(\$input: ProductInput!) { productCreate(input: \$input) { userErrors { field message } product { id options { id name position values optionValues { id name hasVariants } } variants(first: 5) { nodes { id title selectedOptions { name value } } } } } }\",\n \"variables\": {\n    \"input\": {\n      \"title\": \"New product\",\n      \"productOptions\": [\n        {\n          \"name\": \"Color\",\n          \"values\": [\n            {\n              \"name\": \"Red\"\n            },\n            {\n              \"name\": \"Green\"\n            }\n          ]\n        },\n        {\n          \"name\": \"Size\",\n          \"values\": [\n            {\n              \"name\": \"Small\"\n            },\n            {\n              \"name\": \"Medium\"\n            }\n          ]\n        }\n      ]\n    }\n  }\n}");

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

